# How to set the default model to a variable if None was passed?

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, pydantic

Can I make a default model in Pydantic if None is passed in the field?

I am new to pydantic and searched for relevant answers but could not find any. I have the following code,

```
from typing import Optional,List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class FieldInfo(BaseModel):
    value: Optional[str] = ""
    confidence: Optional[float] = -1.0


class UserInfo(BaseModel):
    first_name: Optional[FieldInfo]
    last_name: Optional[FieldInfo]

user_info = {"user":{"first_name":["john",0.98], "last_name":["doe",0.98]}}
user = UserInfo(**{k:{"value":v[0],"confidence":v[1]} for k,v in user_info["user"].items()})
print(user)
```

gives me

```
first_name=FieldInfo(value='john', confidence=0.98) last_name=FieldInfo(value='doe', confidence=0.98)
```

but if last_name is None i.e.

```
user_info = {"user":{"first_name":["john",0.98]}}
user = UserInfo(**{k:{"value":v[0],"confidence":v[1]} for k,v in user_info["user"].items()})
print(user)
```

I get

```
first_name=FieldInfo(value='john', confidence=0.98) last_name=None
```

How can i get it take the default value if there is no values is passed, like below

```
first_name=FieldInfo(value='john', confidence=0.98) last_name=FieldInfo(value='', confidence=-1.0)
```

Comment: try `last_name: Optional[FieldInfo] = FieldInfo(value='', confidence=-1.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just include adding a default value in `UserInfo.last_name` like so:

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class FieldInfo(BaseModel):
    value: Optional[str] = ""
    confidence: Optional[float] = -1.0


class UserInfo(BaseModel):
    first_name: Optional[FieldInfo]
    # Note I've added `= FieldInfo(...)` below
    last_name: Optional[FieldInfo] = FieldInfo(value='', confidence=-1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you. actually, I tried similar method, but I did not explicitly give value and confidence in the optional I just passed  ```last_name: Optional[FieldInfo] = FieldInfo('',1.0)```. I got ```TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (3 given)```. But this is working.